# Cube 3D rotation - direction bug (Javascript - CSS3)

Tags: javascript, css, cube

I'm doing a 3D cube with CSS3 animating with touch events. Here's the link (you can activate "touch events" in Chrome): http://adevby.me/cube/ .

I made two diffents functions (cube1 & cube2). The only change is line 254 for the second cube.

**First cube:**
When you make a 180 deg rotation on the Y axis (red face at the bottom), then a rotation on the X axis, the direction is reversed (relative to the cursor / finger movement).

**Second cube:**
So i tried to make a condition when we are less than -90deg && more than 90deg on the Y axis, but we see a bad transition ...

**Second problem**
When you have the red face in front of you, and you make a movement on the X axis, the cube turn on the Z axis, and not the Y axis.

I hope I'm clear ...

Comment: I'm running Chrome and I don't see cubes, just butterfly/tie-fighter shapes!

Comment: @LeeTaylor I do see cubes, Chromium 20;)

Comment: I've switched to Lynx, still nothing...

Comment: A friend had the same issue on Chrome. He reinstall Chrome and now it works fine ... I don't know why ...

Comment: Hi, I have the same code issue, but with safari. Have you found a solution for this ? Thanks !